# Why does a combined IF/ELSE/OR formula give "0" value in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=IF(C2<>"Online Store", G2=H2; IF(D2<>"SWEATERS", G2=H2, IF(OR(B2="Sept.", B2="Oct.", B2="Nov.", B2="Dec."), G2=H2*2, G2=H2)))

Comment: In which cell are you putting this formula?

Comment: Well, is `G2=H2`?

Comment: Please post the values of all the cells involved.

Comment: If you are putting this formula in G2 then remove all the `G2=` in the formula.  If not, then this will not put the H2 value in G2 as a formula cannot change the value in another cell.  Also, you have both `;` and `,` in the formula, your local settings only allow one either `,` or `;`.

Answer (score 1):

In Cell G2, place the below formula:

```
=IF(AND(C2="Online Stores";D2="Sweaters";OR(B2="Sept";B2="Oct";B2="Nov";B2="Dec")); H2*2; H2)
```

That way, you only check for the condition in which G2 becomes H2*2. That keeps the formula shorter, easier to understand, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

in Cell G2, Place the below formula

```
=IF(C2<>"Online Stores"; H2; IF(D2<>"Sweaters";H2; IF(OR(B2="Sept";B2="Oct";B2="Nov";B2="Dec");H2*2;H2)))
```

[image]